# Acquire data from one table based off multiple conditions from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm experiencing a bit of a problem working out a solution to extract activity from followers in my web application.

I have two newly created tables in the same database; one called `followers` and the other called `activity`. I need to grab the IDs of the users that they follow (column name is `user_id`) and then compose an SQL query to select all the activity entries by the users in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$followers = array();
$ids = array();
foreach($db->query("SELECT user_id FROM followers")->fetchAll() as $follower) {
    $ids[] = $follower["user_id"];
    $follower["activities"] = array();
    $followers[$follower["user_id"]] = $follower;
}
foreach($db->query("SELECT id, user_id, activityInfos FROM activity WHERE user_id IN(". implode(", ", $ids) .")")->fetchAll() as $activity) {
    $followers[$activity["user_id"]]["activities"][] = $activity;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! How would I go about muddling them all up and ordering by date with this method?

Comment: You want to order the followers ? you just have to execute this query.

    SELECT user_id FROM followers ORDER BY date